# docker-compose.yml syntax leads to error in runtime

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, devops

Is there any difference between these two configs:

Config 1:

```yaml
...
environment:
  - POSTGRES_NAME='postgres'
  - POSTGRES_USER='postgres'
  - POSTGRES_PASSWORD='postgres'
  - POSTGRES_PORT='5432'
```

Config 2:

```yaml
...
environment:
  - POSTGRES_NAME=postgres
  - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
  - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
  - POSTGRES_PORT=5432
```

Because, when I try to `docker-compose up` with **Config 1** it throws an error (`django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"`), and it works fine with **Config 2**. What is wrong with docker-compose.yml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a [YAML scalar](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#73-flow-scalar-styles), the *entire string* can be quoted, but quotes inside a string are interpreted literally as quotes.  (This is a different behavior than, say, the Bourne shell.)

So in this fragment:

```yaml
environment:
  - POSTGRES_NAME='postgres'
```

The value of `environment:` is a YAML list.  Each list item contains a YAML string.  The string is the literal string `POSTGRES_NAME='postgres'`, including the single quotes.  Compose then splits this on the equals sign and sets the variable `POSTGRES_NAME` to the value `'postgres'`, including the single quotes.

There's two ways to work around this.  One is to not quote anything; even if there are "special characters" after the equals sign, it will still be interpreted as part of the value.

```yaml
environment:
  - CONTAINING_SPACES=any string
  - CONTAINING_EQUALS=1+1=2
  - CONTAINING_QUOTES="double quotes outside, 'single quotes' inside"
```

A second way is to use the alternate syntax for `ENVIRONMENT` that's a YAML mapping instead of a list of strings.  You'd then use YAML (not shell) quoting for the value part (and the key part if you'd like).

```yaml
environment:
  POSTGRES_NAME: 'postgres'     # YAML single quoting
  CONTAINING_SPACES: any string # YAML string rules don't require quotes
  START_WITH_STAR: '*star'      # not a YAML anchor
  'QUOTED_NAME': if you want    # syntactically valid
```

Answer (score 0):

...
environment:

- POSTGRES_NAME='postgres'
- POSTGRES_USER='postgres'
- POSTGRES_PASSWORD='postgres'
- POSTGRES_PORT='5432'

Comment: so what's that?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).